# Select one table row to join to each row from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Departments and Accounts. Ex:

**Departments**

```
+--------+--------+
|Company |DptCode  |
+--------+--------+
|SND     |CD41     |
+--------+--------+
|SND     |CD42     |
+--------+--------+
```

**Accounts**

```
+--------+--------+
|Company |AcctCode |
+--------+--------+
|SND     |ACT      |
+--------+--------+
|SND     |BBS      |
+--------+--------+
|SND     |DIP      |
+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to write a query to select each department joining to bring all of the account codes from the Accounts table, like this

```
+--------+--------+
|DptCode |AcctCode|
+--------+--------+
|CD41    |ACT     |
+--------+--------+
|CD41    |BBS     |
+--------+--------+
|CD41    |DIP     |
+--------+--------+
|CD42    |ACT     |
+--------+--------+
|CD42    |BBS     |
+--------+--------+
|CD42    |DIP     |
+--------+--------+
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to group them if I need to group them or not, I can't wrap my head around how to do this join. When I run the below query, I am getting many duplicate rows.

```
SELECT  d.Company, d.DptCode, a.AcctCode
FROM Departments d
JOIN Accounts a ON d.Company = a.Company
```

Comment: The logic of your join is correct actually, but your select clause is slightly off.  The query you posted won't even run.  Use the correct column names and the query should work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My bad, it was a typos when I was copying and pasting from my sql-server to here.

Comment: So what is the issue here? I created tables and your data using SQL Server 2014 and your query produces what your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using join

```
;WITH CTE_dept(Company ,DptCode  )
AS
(
SELECT 'SND','CD41' UNION ALL    
SELECT 'SND','CD42'  
),CTe_Accounts(Company ,AcctCode )
AS
(
SELECT 'SND','ACT' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'SND','BBS' UNION ALL      
SELECT 'SND','DIP'      
)
SELECT cd.DptCode,
        ca.AcctCode
FROM CTE_dept cd
INNER JOIN CTe_Accounts ca
    ON  ca.Company = cd.Company
```

Result

```
DptCode  AcctCode
-----------------
CD41     ACT
CD41     BBS
CD41     DIP
CD42     ACT
CD42     BBS
CD42     DIP
```

Comment: I don't think a left join is necessary here.  Why not use an inner join?

Comment: This is working as is, but I will need to select from the specified 2 tables instead of hard-coding the values into the CTEs.

Comment: @Truecolor the cte here is replace the table since there wasn't one to work with in your post. In your code you would change the select to pull from your tables, not the ctes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.DptCode, a.AcctCode
FROM Departments d CROSS JOIN
     Accounts a;
```

Comment: Ummm....there is no ON clause for a cross join. A cross join is a cartesian so the ON clause would not make sense.

Comment: @SeanLange But, to note, in some versions of SQL an `INNER JOIN` without an `ON` clause is in fact a `CROSS JOIN` ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen huh? I think you mean an ANSI-89 style join (aka comma separated list of tables)? That is a cross join that is then filtered with where predicates. I am not aware of any version where you can specify an explicit inner join but leave off the join predicates.

Comment: @SeanLange It certainly is possible in MySQL (and SQLite, I think).  Not sure about SQL Server though :-)

Comment: @Tim really? That is just awful. Seems that is a big hole in their engine. An inner join with no predicates should not be a cross join. It should produce a syntax error. It would be too easy to forget your join predicates and get a horribly wrong result. But whatever, every DBMS has some serious quirks to deal with.

Comment: @Sean [Just for your entertainment](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d037b89c32978e47e3c01a64c7604c2d).

Comment: It turns out the Departments table had multiple rows with the same dptCode, but just slightly different description verbiage in its Description column. That was the reason I was seeing duplicate rows in the results. I just have to do distinct dptCodes into a temp table and then will join to the Accounts table. Thanks for the help everyone.